# What's the difference between using a LaunchAgent and checking "Open at Login" in Dock? And how do I access the latter programmatically?

Tags: macos

What's the difference between using a LaunchAgent and checking "Open at Login" in Dock? And how do I access the latter programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally launch agents have more options. They use the launchd process to run them. "Open at Login" basically adds the application to the users startup items. Adding something to a user's startup items requires applescript code. You can google for that as that's how I found it when I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Following link also talks about in more detailed:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html

Please check "Login Item" and "launchd Agent" sections.

Regards,
Anand Choubey